# Link to new popup-window, print area of document

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering how you best open a new window and show a view there using mvc?

and is there a way to using jquery or similar, to print an area of a document? lets say everything within a div?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a new window is easy, you would do it like you would any other way, passing a URL to the content you want to open in the new window whether it be through a link, or a call through Javascript.

The only way that ASP.NET MVC helps here is in the utility functions that can give you the URL of a route or an action which you would then write directly into your view.

As for printing part of a page, a simple Google search on "jQuery print" (not as a phase) turned this up as the second result:

[Ask Ben: Print Part Of A Web Page With jQuery](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("action", "controller", new { target = "_blank" }) %>
```